# SQL Server SELECT shows my own value not from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I'm looking for way to add my data to some columns,

```
select co1, col2, col3 from tbl
```

I want to cod3 exist but only show my data

```
select co1, col2, col3=3 from tbl
```

output should be

```
1, 0, 3
```

I have problem with CR9 and this is only way I guess .

Comment: i want to cod3 exist but only show my data.... what could that mean?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to call the 3rd column col3 just do

```
select co1,col2, '3' as col3 from tbl
```

by the way

```
select co1,col2,col=3 from tbl
```

was valid acceptable but not recommenened by microsoft until SQL2008R2 in 2012 is not accepted anymore

Answer (score 1):

just use "select co1,col2,'3' from tbl".

Comment: the problem is CR9 dos not recognize  the '3'

Answer (score 1):

try this answer

```
select co1,col2, '3' as col3 from tbl
```